# OpenGL Texture Transparency

Tags: c++, opengl, transparency

I'm using C++ and OpenGL to make a basic 2D game, I have a png image with transparent areas for my player. It works perfectly on my laptop and lab computers, but on my desktop the entire image is mostly see through, not just the areas that are meant to be. What could cause/fix this?

Here is the code I've used and is the same on all machines

```
glPushMatrix(); 
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, playerTex);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);

glTranslatef(XPos, YPos, 0.0);
glRotatef(heading, 0,0,1);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(-40,40);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(-40,-40);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(40,-40);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(40,40);
    glEnd();

glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, I changed

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

to

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

and it works correctly, not sure why though.

Comment: Because mipmaps are not more automatically built?

Comment: @LucaPiccioni: Yup, in combination with different resolutions at different computers.

Answer (score 2):

Does setting glColor4f(1,1,1,1) help? (I can't remember if GL_REPLACE is affected by vertex color)

Check glGetError() at appropriate places to see if you're not doing anything really wrong.

Other generic tips:

- try to lock down all loose ends of the render state.
- make sure your PNG-read lib works correctly everywhere. (create texture data in code otherwise)
- It might be hardware related, and then it helps if you list the OS:es and CPU types/drivers.
- I'm assuming you're running the same executable on all computers?

Comment: GL_REPLACE means replace the vertex color (more exactly, the previous stage output), so no, it's not affecting it.

Comment: I tried the glGetError() not getting anything from that

OS: Win 7 32bit and in lab vista 64bit
CPU: on desktop is Intel E6600, some other core 2 duo on laptop
Graphics: on desktop ATI Radeon X1900, laptop Intel Integrated